# iPhone Memory Debugging

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-management

I'm using Instruments to try to determine if there are places in my application that I could be more efficient with use of memory. I've taken the time to get somewhat familiar with Instruments but I'm generally a newbie with hunting memory management issues having come from a Java background. I seem to be using about 1.82mb by calls to this method:

```
+ (NSString *)stringFromDateWithFormat:(NSDate *)date withFormat:(NSString *)format
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    NSString *result;

    if (nil == date || nil == format)
        return nil;

    result = nil;
    if (nil != (dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter allocWithZone:[self zone]] init])) {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];   

        if (nil != (result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date])) {
            [dateFormatter release];
            return result;
        } 

        [dateFormatter release]; 
    } 
    return nil;
}
```

As I'm releasing the date formatter I'm wondering if the NSString *result* is my issue. It seems to me that the stringFromDate library call would return an autoreleased object so there's nothing I can do to 'manually' manage it. A bit unsure of how to optimize this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this method getting called a lot of times in a loop? Autoreleased objects only get released when the NSAutoreleasePool they're in gets released. As I understand it, the default autorelease pool is created and release every event loop. It's possible you're creating too many autoreleased objects in the course of a single event loop. The solution is to create your own NSAutoreleasePool in an appropriate place, and release it to clear up autoreleased objects. An extreme example that illustrates the point:

```
int i;
NSAutoreasePool* pool = nil;
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    /* Create a new pool every 10000 iterations */
    if ((i % 10000) == 0) {
        if (pool) [pool release];
        pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    }
    [someObj someMethodThatCreatesAutoreleasedObjects];
}
[pool release];
```

In that example, the current pool is released every 10,000 iterations and a new one is created. You can read more about memory management in the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Concepts/AutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047) section on autorelease pools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an autoreleased object anyway, so there's really nothing you should be doing about the result string. I don't see any mistakes related to memory, but your code is definitely more verbose than needed. Keep in mind that in Objective-C, if you call a method on nil, you get back nil (or 0 for an integer, but **not** for floating point values). You can take out all those if statements and the two return paths, and your code will still work the same way. Also, I would just use alloc instead of allocWithZone.

Comment: Can you say 'why' you would not use allocWithZone?

Comment: For normal usage it's not needed because your objects will always be allocated on the same, default zone. See this article: http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Concepts/Zones.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% with this. I am also just learning Mac/Iphone development. But you can use the auto release pool to help with memory management. It is used to get around  release problems.

Here is an article with lots on [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Concepts/ObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043). Check out the left sided menu.